# Vue Pivot-Table Label

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, pivot-table

I would like to add labels to a pivot-table in Vue like in the screenshot below, I thought I could do this by injecting HTML into the elements but this leads to upsetting the array indexes. thus making the drag and drop functionality unusable. Is this even possible?

[image]

Is there a better way that this could be implemented?

JSFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/scobbybrady/7wr9kftv/5/)

```
<script src=//unpkg.com/vue></script>
<script src=//unpkg.com/vue-pivottable@0.3.62/dist/vue-pivottable.umd.js></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/vue-pivottable@0.3.62/dist/vue-pivottable.css">
<div id="app">
        <vue-pivottable-ui
            :data="pivotData"
            :aggregator-name="aggregatorName"
            :renderer-name="rendererName"
            :rows="rows"
            :cols="cols"
            :vals="vals"
            :row-total="true"
            :col-total="true"
        >
        </vue-pivottable-ui>
</div>
```

```
window.Vue.use(window['vue-pivottable'])
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      pivotData: [
  ['Total Bill', 'Tip', 'Payer Gender', 'Payer Smoker', 'Day of Week', 'Meal', 'Party Size'],
  [16.99, 1.01, 'Female', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 2],
  [10.34, 1.66, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 3],
  [21.01, 3.5, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 3],
  [23.68, 3.31, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 2],
  [24.59, 3.61, 'Female', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 4],
  [25.29, 4.71, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 4],
  [8.77, 2, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 2],
  [26.88, 3.12, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 4],
  [15.04, 1.96, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 2],
  [14.78, 3.23, 'Male', 'Non-Smoker', 'Sunday', 'Dinner', 2],
],
      aggregatorName: 'Sum',
      rendererName: 'Table Heatmap',
      rows: ['Payer Gender'],
      cols: ['Party Size'],
      vals: ['Total Bill'],
  },
  mounted() {
    const pvtUnused = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'pvtAxisContainer pvtUnused pvtHorizList'
    )
    const pvtCols = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'pvtAxisContainer pvtHorizList pvtCols'
    )
    const pvtRows = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'pvtAxisContainer pvtVertList pvtRows'
    )
    if (pvtUnused.length !== 0) {
      pvtUnused[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h4>Unused Data</h4>')
    }
    if (pvtCols.length !== 0) {
      pvtCols[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h4>Column Data</h4>')
    }
    if (pvtRows.length !== 0) {
      pvtRows[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h4>Row Data</h4>')
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: follow this example to nice way :- https://github.com/Seungwoo321/vue-pivottable/tree/master/demo/example-vue-cli3

Comment: @ANISHKUMARMOURYA Thanks but that doesn't resolve the question I actually asked

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the [documentation](https://seungwoo321.github.io/vue-pivottable/guide/slot.html#renderercell) there are slots for `rendererCell`, `AggregatorCell`, `colGroup`, and `output`. None of which do what you are looking for.